# Cart and checkout page woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, woocommerce

I have two identical sites: one hosted on google cloud and another on site ground. Both of them have same plugins, themes and configuration. Except PHP version.

1 - google cloud server 16 Core with 64 GB RAM
2 - site ground shared server

When i'm trying to access cart and checkout page on site ground it's taking three seconds, but google cloud is taking 25 Seconds to start loading the page. Any hints or support why this delay on live site?

thank you

Comment: Is every pageload on your Google Cloud server slow? Or just the first one in a few hours? What do you see if you install the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin? You're probably paying a small fortune for that server. They may have tech support to help you. If not, well, fire them and get a better cloud service.

Comment: just cart and checkout page rather than this all working fine with CDN i'll try query monitor and see thanks a lot

Comment: What is your GCP setup? Is it just a Compute Engine instance or do you have more options, e.g. load balancing enabled?

Comment: it's Only compute engine with DNS setup

Comment: after digging with the problem i found it's from number of hops at google cloud server cause like 25 seconds just to reach the server? any support in this case

Comment: Can you post a traceroute result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools such as [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace) to diagnose the delay.
If it's being cuased by routing on the Google network, you can report it via [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) ot contact [Google Cloud Support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support).